# How to secure images with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gallery

I have a gallery in my rails app that needs to only allow certain images to be shown to specific, logged in users.  I am using Paperclip for image processing now, but it saves all images in a public folder available to anyone.

Note that I don't have to use Paperclip if there is a better way, and I already have the login system in place.  I just need a way to place the images in a non-public location, but still be able to serve them as needed.

Is it possible to only allow these images to be served to authenticated users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://wiki.github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/interpolations) you can find how to change the path of the uploaded pictures. If you have done this. You need to create a controller which serves these static files.

For Example: [Paperclip sample app part 2: downloading files through a controller](http://patshaughnessy.net/2009/5/16/paperclip-sample-app-part-2-downloading-files-through-a-controller)

> Is it possible to only allow these
>   images to be served to authenticated
>   users?

Yes, you just need to check if the user is logged in in the controller action responsible for the image.